# Django Function after action decorator is being ignored

Tags: python, django

## I have this View in django and when I do the post request it ignores the logic in my function completely and will do a post and then return the object, I am wondering how I can have it follow my logic

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend
from rest_framework import mixins, serializers, viewsets
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
from apps.units.models import Unit

from apps.api.mixins import DestroyModelMixin
from apps.api.v1.decorators import action
from apps.leads.models import Leads
from .serializers import LeadSerializer
from apps.api.v1.units.serializers import UnitSerializer


class LeadsViewSet(
    mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
    mixins.ListModelMixin,
    viewsets.GenericViewSet,
    mixins.CreateModelMixin,
    mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
    DestroyModelMixin,
  
                        ):
    serializer_class = LeadSerializer
    queryset = Leads.objects.all()


     
    @action(methods=["POST"], detail=False,)
    def create_lead(self, request, pk=None, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            date = request.body.get("date")
            user_id = request.body.get("user_id")
            unit_id = request.body.get("unit_id")
            existing_lead = self.queryset.filter(user_id=user_id, unit_id=unit_id).exists()
            if existing_lead:
                 raise serializers.ValidationError(_("Lead already exists"))
            Leads.objects.create(
                user_id=user_id,
                unit_id=unit_id,
                date=date
            )
            return ({"message":"Lead Created Succesfully"})
        except Exception as e:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(_("Lead not created"))
```

Answer (score 0):

in your current implementation you're trying to access data from request body but you're using `request.body.get` which returns a bytes-like object.
you should parse the request data properly also you might want to use the `CreateModelMixin` rather than defining a custom method for creating leads like this:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from rest_framework import mixins, serializers, viewsets, status
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from rest_framework.response import Response
from apps.leads.models import Leads
from .serializers import LeadSerializer

class LeadsViewSet(
    mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
    mixins.ListModelMixin,
    viewsets.GenericViewSet,
    mixins.CreateModelMixin,
    mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
    mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
):
    serializer_class = LeadSerializer
    queryset = Leads.objects.all()

    @action(methods=["POST"], detail=False,)
    def create_lead(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            date = request.data.get("date")
            user_id = request.data.get("user_id")
            unit_id = request.data.get("unit_id")
            
            existing_lead = self.queryset.filter(user_id=user_id, unit_id=unit_id).exists()
            if existing_lead:
                raise serializers.ValidationError(_("Lead already exists"))

            Leads.objects.create(
                user_id=user_id,
                unit_id=unit_id,
                date=date
            )
            return Response({"message": "Lead Created Successfully"}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        except Exception as e:
            return Response({"error": "Lead not created"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

my changes:
using `request.data` instead of `request.body` to access parsed POST data

returning a proper HTTP response using `Response` from Django REST Framework

using appropriate HTTP status code in the response.

I hope this helps you